# Linear Transformations in Linear Alg

Tags: linear-algebra

Does there exist a linear transformation $T : R^3 → R^3$ such that
$ T
\left(\begin{bmatrix}
6
\\ -3 
\\ 3
\end{bmatrix}\right) $ =  $
\begin{bmatrix}
1
\\2
\\ 3  
\end{bmatrix} $ and $ T 
\left(\begin{bmatrix}
4
\\ -2 
\\ 2
\end{bmatrix}\right) $ =  $
\begin{bmatrix}
2
\\4
\\ 6  
\end{bmatrix} $ How do I go about solving this problem? Looking for some help with my midterm review

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observe that

$$\begin{pmatrix}4\\-2\\2\end{pmatrix}=\frac23\begin{pmatrix}6\\-3\\3\end{pmatrix}$$ , so it must be

$$T\begin{pmatrix}4\\-2\\2\end{pmatrix}=\frac23\;T\begin{pmatrix}6\\-3\\3\end{pmatrix}$$

because of linearity. Is this true?

Comment: @geohelp Good. Then there cannot exist such... *linear*...transformation.

Comment: @geohelp Precisely. And if asked, you must argue that a linear transformation fulfills, for **any** vector $\;v\;$ and **any** scalar $\;k\;$ , that $\;T(kv)=kTv\;$ , and since in the present case this isn't so the transformation cannot be linear.

Answer (score 3):

Notice that the input vectors are multiples of each other and that the output vectors are multiples of each other.  Since those multiples are not the same, such a transform doesn't exist.

Comment: is that all I would need to say? is there a mathematical representation of what you just explained?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**
Both input vectors are multiples of $\mathbf{u}=\begin{bmatrix}2\\-1\\1\end{bmatrix}$. Then $T(\lambda\mathbf{u})=\lambda(T(\mathbf{u}))$.

**Added explanation:**

You are given that $T(3\mathbf{u})=\begin{bmatrix}1\\2\\3\end{bmatrix}$, this means 
$$T(3\mathbf{u})=3T(\mathbf{u})=\begin{bmatrix}1\\2\\3\end{bmatrix}.$$
But when you use the other condition, you get
$$T(2\mathbf{u})=2T(\mathbf{u})=\begin{bmatrix}2\\4\\6\end{bmatrix}.$$

So you are getting two different values for $T(\mathbf{u})$. Hence such a T cannot exist.

Comment: okay so where do I go from there?

Answer (score 0):

If $T$ exists, we will have

$T(6,-3,3)=T(3(2,-1,1))=3T(2,-1,1)=(1,2,3)$

thus $T(2,-1,1)=\frac{1}{3}(1,2,3)$

and

$T(4,-2,2)=T(2(2,-1,1))=2T(2,-1,1)=(2,4,6)$

which gives

$T(2,-1,1)=(1,2,3)\neq \frac{1}{3}(1,2,3)$

so, such a linear application doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

This post answers **how to find the matrix of a transformation**
calculated *with respect to the standard basis*, E = {e1, e2, e3}

The **same pattern** goes if I want to **calculate the transformation T with respect to another basis**, for general example **some basis**, B = {b1, b2, b3}

**Firstly you determine T(ei)**, as vectors:

**Then, you apply Gauss Elimination method on vectors**,

on Ri rows in order to find T(ei),
for each i.

Place them as columns to A matrix, empty matrix.

T would normally be the transformation defined by A matrix.

Finally, **T would be T(x) = A*x**, and x = (x, y, z)

***T(x, y, z) = [T(e1), T(e2), T(e3)](x, y, z)***

**So the solution for this exercise goes like:**

T(6, −3, 3) = (1, 2, 3) => 6T(e1) -3T(e2) +3T(e3) = (1, 2, 3)  :R1

T(4, −2, 2) = (2, 4, 6) => 4T(e1) -2T(e2) +2T(e3) = (2, 4, 6)  :R2

R2 <- R2 - 2*R1/3 => (2, 4, 6) -2*(1, 2, 3)/3 = (0, 0, 0) =>
[2-2/3]*(1, 2, 3) = (0, 0, 0)

So, no such transformation exists.

Comment: Hi nzevgolisda. We have a Latex-like typesetting system for mathematical expressions, called MathJax. Information is here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10164